# Start time always getting same in Perl for my script

Tags: perl

I have made a script to extract the content of log files and to calculate the time difference if the task is complete.

Suppose I have four jobs and each job has thre individual tasks, so far I need the start of each task, and just print it.

Everything is fine except when I try to initialise to make it convenient, by using `$j`, `$l` which are used as sort of two-dimensional array.

The problem is at the output where I get the same "Started at" for each job.

The values of `$counter` and `$l` should be the root cause.

Can anyone help? I tried my best and am sort of newbie.

```
sub getdate {
    my $line = $_[0];

    ($hrs, $min) = split(':', $line, 3);
    return $hrs, $min;
}

print FILE "<html><head>\n";
print FILE "<title>CGI Test</title>\n";
print FILE "</head>\n";
print FILE "<body>";
print FILE "<font size=\"5\" color=\"#008080\" face=\"Tahoma\"><b><u><br>";
print FILE "PBI Batch for 22/02/2013";
print FILE "</font></b></u><br><br><br>";

my $i = 0;
my $j = 0;
my $l = 0;

my @sample;

#print FILE "<h4>";

foreach $header (<COLLECTION>) {
    chomp($header);
    ($heading, $filepath) = split(',', $header);

    #$two[$i]="<font size=\"3\"color=\"#008000\" face=\"Tahoma\"><b><u><br>";
    #$two[$i]="<font size=\"3\" color=".$color." face=\"Tahoma\"><b><u><br>";
    $two[$i] .= $heading;

    #$two[$i] .= "</font></u></b><br>";
    #print FILE "<font size=\"3\" color=\"#008000\" face=\"Tahoma\"><b><u><br>";
    #       print FILE $two[$i];
    #print FILE $heading;
    #print FILE "</font></u></b><br>";

    #print $filepath."\n";
    open(MYFILE1, $filepath) or die 'Could nont openfile';

    my $counter;
    foreach $list (<MYFILE1>) {

        chomp($list);
        ($file, $path) = split(',', $list);

        #print FILE $file;
        my @secondstart;
        my @secondend;
        my $secondcounter = 0;

        #print FILE "valueofllllllllllllllllllllllllllll".$l;
        foreach $counter ($file) {
            print FILE "valueofllllllllllllllllllllllllllll" . $l;
            $l++;
            $sample[$j][$l] = $counter;
            print FILE "secCOUNTER  " . $secondcounter;
            $secondcounter++;
        }

        print FILE "                                space";

        open(MYFILE, $path) or die 'ERRROR';
        my $count = 0;
        foreach $line (<MYFILE>) {

            my @endtime;

            $flag = 'false';

            #$counter++;
            $count++;
            print FILE $count . "========";

            if ($count == 1) {
                ($hrs, $min) = getdate($line);
                $starttime[$j][$l] = ($hrs * 60) + $min;
            }
            else {
                ($hrs, $min) = split(':', $line, 3);
                if ($line =~ m/End of Procedure/) {
                    $flag            = 'true';
                    $endtime[$j][$l] = $hrs . $min;
                    $endtime[$j][$l] = ($hrs * 60) + $min;
                }
                else {
                    $endtime[$j][$l] = ($hrs * 60) + $min;
                }
            }

            $duration[$j][$l] = $endtime[$j][$l] - $starttime[$j][$l];

        }

        #   print $flag;

        #print FILE $file." : ";
        #print FILE "value of ".$j."and".$l;
        $startstatus[$j][$l]    = "Started at" . $starttime[$j][$l];
        $durationstatus[$j][$l] = "&nbspDuration is " . $duration[$j][$l] . "m";

        # print FILE "Started at".$starttime;
        # print FILE "&nbspDuration is ".$duration."m";

        #                 print FILE "<br>";

        close(MYFILE);

    }

    my $valueofl = $l;

    #print FILE "vlaeeofl".$valueofl;
    print "valueofllllllllllllllllllllllllllll" . $l;
    $l = 0;

    if ($flag eq 'true') {
        $status = 'Completed';
        $color  = '#008000';

        print FILE "<font size=\"3\" color=" 
            . $color
            . " face=\"Tahoma\"><b><u><br>"
            . $two[$i]
            . "</font></u></b><br>";
        print FILE $status . "<br>";

        while ($l <= $valueofl) {

            #print $j."and".$l;
            #   print "valueofllllllllllllllllllllllllllll".$l;

            print FILE $sample[$j][$l] . "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
            print FILE $startstatus[$j][$l] . "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
            print FILE $durationstatus[$j][$l] . "<br>";
            $l++;
        }

        # print FILE $startstatus[$j][0];
        # print FILE $durationstatus[$j][0];
    }
    else {
        #print "valueofllllllllllllllllllllllllllll".$l;
        #print $j."and".$l;
        $status = 'In Progress';
        $color  = 'blue';
        print FILE "<font size=\"3\" color=" 
            . $color
            . " face=\"Tahoma\"><b><u><br>"
            . $two[$i]
            . "</font></u></b><br>"
            . $status;
    }
    $i++;
    $j++;

}

print FILE "</body>";
print FILE "</html>";

close(FILE);
close(MYFILE1)
```

Comment: You should cut down your code so that it makes up the smallest possible sample that still demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 4):

This is a shocking piece of Perl. You must *always* start you program with `use strict` and `use warnings`, and declare all variables as close as possible to their first point of use using `my`. That is the most basic form of debugging, and it is only polite to do this at the very least before asking other people for help.

The problem is likely to lie in your `for` statement

```
foreach $counter ($file) { ... }
```

which will execute the body of the loop just *once*, with `$content` set to the value of `$file`. I can't imagine what you meant it to do.

Comment: with `$content` aliased to `$file`